# I have TabLayout in Fragment and then used FragmentTransaction to intent from Main Activity to Fragment

Tags: android

I have TabLayout in Fragment and then used FragmentTransaction to intent from Main Activity to Fragment, But When Transaction from Activity to Fragment Show this Problem.

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.Toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view. findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    //  setupTabIcons();
   return view;
}

// Add Fragments to Tabs
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
 // ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new AllFragment() ,"All");
    adapter.addFrag(new ManFragment(),"Man");
    adapter.addFrag(new WomenFragment(),"Women");
    adapter.addFrag( new KidsFragment(),"Kids");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

MainActivivty :
[image]

Comment: make sure u have import "import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;" 
not "import android.app.FragmentTransaction;"

Comment: Show Error in FragmeentTransaction because of requirement import android.app.FragmentTransaction

Comment: for v4 FragmentTransaction you need to use it like this
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();